# My Query is getting the wrong data

Tags: categories, loop, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to populate a select box to get the categories created in my ACF post type, when clicked these will filter available jobs via their category. The post type can be seen here - [Post Type](http://gyazo.com/c64377627e76abac997a2fd7fb433327)

Currently my query returns the 4 categories to the select box which correspond with the posts rendered later on in my code, rather than rendering all of my categories.

My category query can be seen here -

```
    <?php 
    $the_args = array (
        'post_type' => 'jobs',
        the_field('job_category') 
    );

    $option_query = new WP_Query( $the_args );
?>

    <form action="">
        <select name="job_cats">
            <?php if (have_posts()) : while ( $option_query->have_posts()) : $option_query->the_post(); ?>
                <option value="<?php the_field('job_category'); ?>"><?php the_field('job_category'); ?></option>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </select>
    </form>

    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I tried to add the reset_query function before running this function below, but the same results persist to render to the select box.

```
<?php 
    $cat_filter = '';
    $node_id = 0;
    $node_count = 0;

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'jobs',
        'meta_key' => 'job_category',
        'meta_value' => $cat_filter
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while ( $the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); $node_id++ ?>
        <div class="search-node node<?php echo $node_id ?>"> 
             <?php get_template_part( 'post' , 'jobs') ?> 
        </div>
        <hr id="divider<?php echo $node_id ?>" class="search-divider">
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
          <p class="none-found">Sorry, we currently have no jobs available, keep watching this space!</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Any pointers would be appreciated, I am relatively new to wordpress so I am sure I have made a small mistake!

Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$the_args = array (
    'post_type' => 'jobs',
    the_field('job_category') 
);
```

The trouble here is that `the_field( 'job_category' )` *prints* data, so using it to build an array is pretty much useless. You're left with literally `post_type = job`.

However, the real problem is that you actually need to grab the category *options*, not the posts that you attach them to. That's why, when you run your loop, you just end up with a select that corresponds to each post's category.

A quick gander at [the ACF documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/select/) reveals...

```
$field = get_field_object('field_name');
$value = get_field('field_name');
$label = $field['choices'][ $value ];
```

This gives us a pretty clear idea of how to interact with data stored by ACF. `$field['choices']` appears to be an associative array of the choices (categories), the key being the "field" & the value being the "label". With this info, let's have a crack at building that `select`:

```
<?php if ( $field = get_field_object( 'job_category' ) ) : ?>
    <select name="job_cats">
        <?php foreach ( $field['choices'] as $name => $label ) ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $name ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $label ) ?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
<?php endif ?>
```

Hope this helps, and let us know if you're unsure of anything, or if it doesn't work! :)

Comment: Brilliant this solved the problem! Thanks a lot, I feel silly when I can't work simple things like this out, makes a lot of sense now looking at your code :).